# how to setup a public dns server?

Tags: domain-name-system

I just installed powerdns, and I added the record 
example.com A 120 1.2.3.4
and I used dig to see if it works, and it works. 
dig @localhost example.com
and it will show the correct ip address : 1.2.3.4

My question is how to use this dns server in the public, so that my domain example.com to be dig without the @localhost?

I will need the ns1.example.com ns2.example.com to be pointed to my 2 powerdns server ip, and I need to use my dns server to set the ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com, so that my other products could also setup ns1.example.com as their dns server, so how to do this?Edit

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something you can do locally, because the rest of the world needs to know about it.

You need to set the server(s) as authoritative at your domain registrar.  All the registrars provide some sort of interface for doing this configuration in their domain administration pages.